# While testing SFINAE, I found something that I don't think should work

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae

I found an interesting conditional function exclusion that I got from [this site](https://rmf.io/cxx11/almost-static-if) and while testing it I came across this:

```c++
#include<type_traits>

namespace detail
{
    enum enabler {};
}

template <int overload, typename Condition>
using EnableIf = std::enable_if_t<Condition::value, detail::enabler>;

template <typename T,
    EnableIf<0, std::is_same<T, int>>...>
    T twice(T t) { return 2 * t; }

template <typename T,
    EnableIf<0, std::is_same<T, float>>...>
    T twice(T t) { return 2 * t; }

int main()
{
    twice(1);
    twice(1.f);
    return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't this cause a compiler error because the `EnableIf` type are the same in both functions?  I was going to use a different number for each overload and have a template class that would contain the enabler enum so that it would be a different type, but it would seem that it isn't necessary.  Is this a defect or am I missing something?

I've tested this on VC++ (2017) and [clang](https://ideone.com/Rv3xnO).

Although VC++ compiler doesn't complain, apparently the intellisense doesn't like it:

[image]

Which is what I thought, but it complains regardless if I use a different integer, or even go to the trouble of doing what I said I was going to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was too quick on the draw and marked [Barry's answer](/a/42773472) as the correct answer.  However it would seem that it is not quite right, or at least not clear.

A function can have a valid overload so long as its parameters are different.  A template function is the same, but its signature also includes the template parameters.  Thus, you can have the same function name with the same parameter list, but with different template parameters, and it will still be considered an overload.

So, if both functions were viable with the same type `T`, then there would be a collision.

However, since there is a `EnableIf` that would resolve to a type only under mutually exclusive conditions, then even though the 2nd template type would resolve to the same type `detail::enabler`, the first template parameter would be a different type (this would still work even if there was no auto deduction based on function parameters, with the same function parameter types).  Thus, this would *still* be a different function overload.

To what @Barry said that `std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, int>::value, detail::enabler>` and `std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, float>::value, detail::enabler>` being entirely unrelated types. He is sort of correct. When valid, they do resolve to *exactly* the same type, but what he failed to mention was that they are just not ever valid at the same time.

Comment: "*what he failed to mention was that they are just not ever valid at the same time*" Given the actual conditions involved (`std::is_same<T, int>` vs `std::is_same<T, float>`), did he really have to? That's about as obviously-mutually-exclusive as it gets...  ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn, yes, I believe so.  Traversing a type tree requires trying to parse complex statements.  Someone who is ramping up on this might not immediately see this.  I was scratching my head for a day trying to understand why this resulted in *unrelated types*.  They are unrelated only because they are mutually exclusive. I couldn't see that, and I would rate myself as an intermediate template metaprogrammer.

Comment: Fair enough. :-]

Answer (score 3):

> Shouldn't this cause a compiler error because the `EnableIf` type are the same in both functions?

But they're not the same. One takes a pack of `std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, int>::value, detail::enabler>` and the other takes a pack of `std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, float>::value, detail::enabler>`. Those are entirely unrelated types, so you are declaring two unrelated function templates. Indeed, at least one of those two types is ill-formed, so they cannot have the same type - at best both are ill-formed.

This is perfectly fine. The different number is not only unnecessary, but also wouldn't do anything - alias templates are transparent, so the number would disappear since you're not using it in the actual type expression.

Only if both `EnableIf` conditions *were* viable, *then* you'd end up with the same type (`detail::enabler`) in both functions.

Comment: Side question: why is `EnableIf<0, std::is_same<T, U>>...` even valid given there is no pack to expand?

Comment: @ildjarn It's not expanding a pack, it's declaring a non-type template parameter pack. Basically it's just like `int...`, except with a longer type name.

Comment: Ah! Peculiar, but I see it now. Thanks